# PowerCLI: Error retrieving file for VIB ... '_SharedFile' object has no attribute 'writing' when export depot to iso

Tags: powercli

I would like to export depot to iso in PowerCLI. Adding depot, adding packages, changing acceptance level, export to offline bundle have been done. But export to ISO doesn't work.

I did "export-esximageprofile -imageprofile Community -exporttoiso -filepath 'ESXi-6.5-Custom_r8168_al.iso' -nosignaturecheck -Force". But I received error like this:

export-esximageprofile : Error retrieving file for VIB 'VMW_bootbank_shim-vmklinux-9-2-3-0_6.5.0-0.0.4564106': ('vib20/shim-vmklinux-9-2-3-0/VMW_bootbank_shim-vmklinux-9-2-3-0_6.5.0-0.0.4564106.vib', "Unable to open VIB archive in streaming mode: '_SharedFile' object
has no attribute 'writing'").
At line:1 char:1

- export-esximageprofile -imageprofile Community -exporttoiso -filepath ...
- 
- CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-EsxImageProfile], FaultException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.FaultException,VMware.ImageBuilder.Commands.ExportProfile

What is wrong? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Product Interoperability Matrix
[PowerCLI vs ESXi - Interoperability Results](https://interopmatrix.vmware.com/Interoperability?col=299,&row=1,&isHidePatch=true&isHideGenSupported=false&isHideTechSupported=true&isHideCompatible=false&isHideNTCompatible=false&isHideIncompatible=false&isHideNotSupported=true&isCollection=false)
VMware has dropped support for ESXi/vSphere 6.5 and 6.7 starting PowerCLI version 13.x. ESXi versions 6.5 and 6.7 are supported only by PowerCLI version 12.7 or earlier.

Have you tried to downgrade ImageBuilder and DeployAutomation modules?
On the VMware forum this question is marked as Answered.
[Error retrieving file for VIB ... '_SharedFile' object has no attribute 'writing'](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/Error-retrieving-file-for-VIB-SharedFile-object-has-no-attribute/m-p/2960511/highlight/true#M287279)

The advice is to downgrade the ImageBuilder module first:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.ImageBuilder | Uninstall-Module -Force
Install-Module -Name VMware.ImageBuilder -RequiredVersion 7.0.3.19599828
```

Also note that it is not sufficient to downgrade only the VMware.ImageBuilder module.
There is a dependent module called VMware.DeployAutomation.
If you'll try to use ImageBuilder without downgrading all dependent modules you'll get an error from PowerCLI notifying you about dependency issues.

To downgrade all dependent modules (from 8.x to 7.x, alternate numeration used, don't mess with PowerCLI version numeration) use the following command:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware* | where { ($_.RequiredModules.Name -contains 'VMware.ImageBuilder') -and ($_.RequiredModules.Version -like '8.*') } | foreach { Uninstall-Module $_.Name -Force; Install-Module $_.Name -MaximumVersion "7.9.9" }
```

In case of errors just downgrade the VMware.DeployAutomation module only:

```
"VMware.DeployAutomation" | foreach { Get-Module -ListAvailable $_ | where { $_.Version -Like "8.*" } | Uninstall-Module -Force ; Install-Module $_ -MaximumVersion "7.9.9" }
```

After downgrading feel free to verify resulted module versions (should be 7.0.3.19599828):

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.ImageBuilder | ft Name,Version -AutoSize
Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.DeployAutomation | ft Name,Version -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, most of the people are reporting that this '*_SharedFile*' error is caused by a **Python-related issue**.

To resolve the issue just upgrade Python from 3.7.0 to **3.7.9** , upgrade PIP and reinstall 'six psutil lxml pyopenssl' packages.

See links below for details:

[Heads Up - Unable to open VIB archive in streaming mode using Export-EsxImageProfile with PowerCLI 13.0](https://williamlam.com/2022/11/heads-up-unable-to-open-vib-archive-in-streaming-mode-using-export-esximageprofile-with-powercli-13-0.html#comment-67215)

[VMWare.Imagebuilder has issue with Python 3.7 and running Add-EsxSoftwareDepot](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/VMWare-Imagebuilder-has-issue-with-Python-3-7-and-running-Add/td-p/2940167)

[Several AttributeError in zipfile seek() methods](https://bugs.python.org/issue34035)

[PowerCLI 13 update and installation hurdles on Windows](https://blog.zuthof.nl/2022/11/30/powercli-13-update-and-installation-hurdles-on-windows/)